# Receiving TypeError: AWS.RDSDataService is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Attempting to use the RDSDataService in AWS Lambda as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
})
AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  rdsdataservice: '2018-08-01',
  // other service API versions
};

const rdsdataservice = new AWS.RDSDataService();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  callback(null, 'ok')      
};
```

And receiving error:

> "errorMessage": "AWS.RDSDataService is not a constructor",
>    "errorType": "TypeError",
>    "stackTrace": [
>      "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
>      "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
>      "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
>      "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
>      "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)",
>      "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
>      "require (internal/module.js:11:18)"

Nodejs version: 8.10

Any idea what's going on? I've set region and API version

Comment: Have you tested it locally? I have and it works...just trying to troubleshoot what might be going on with you

Comment: What is the 'aws-sdk' package version?

Comment: Thank you @eL_Finito and Thales - I just tried creating a custom layer in aws-lambda and uploaded an archive containing node deps: "aws-sdk": "^2.4.27.0" and no longer receive this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It have to works with the latest aws-sdk package.

You can check the package version with this command:

```
npm show aws-sdk version
```

You can check the released versions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk